# Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?

Tags: http, go, url-rewriting, server, url-routing

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Directory structure:

```
%GOPATH%/src/project_name/main.go
%GOPATH%/src/project_name/static/..files and folders ..
```

Even after reading the documentation I have trouble understanding what exactly `http.StripPrefix` does here.

1) Why can't I access `localhost:8080/static` if I remove `http.StripPrefix`?

2) What URL maps to `/static` folder if I remove that function?

Comment: Did you try http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/")))?

Comment: `http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("")))` works.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[`http.StripPrefix()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) forwards the handling of the request to one you specify as its parameter, but before that it modifies the request URL by stripping off the specified prefix.

So for example in your case if the browser (or an HTTP client) requests the resource:

```
/static/example.txt
```

`StripPrefix` will cut the `/static/` and forward the modified request to the handler returned by [`http.FileServer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) so it will see that the requested resource is

```
/example.txt
```

The `Handler` returned by `http.FileServer()` will look for and serve the content of a file *relative* to the folder (or rather `FileSystem`) specified as its parameter (you specified `"static"` to be the root of static files).

Now since `"example.txt"` is in the `static` folder, you have to specify a relative path to that to get the corrent file path.

### Another Example

This example can be found on the http package documentation page ([here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_StripPrefix)):

```
// To serve a directory on disk (/tmp) under an alternate URL
// path (/tmpfiles/), use StripPrefix to modify the request
// URL's path before the FileServer sees it:
http.Handle("/tmpfiles/",
        http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))
```

**Explanation:**

`FileServer()` is told the root of static files is `"/tmp"`. We want the URL to start with `"/tmpfiles/"`. So if someone requests `"/tempfiles/example.txt"`, we want the server to send the file `"/tmp/example.txt"`.

In order to achieve this, we have to strip `"/tmpfiles"` from the URL, and the remaining will be the relative path compared to the root folder `"/tmp"` which if we join gives:

```
/tmp/example.txt
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, make sure you have the trailing slash in `/tmpfiles/` or you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: to clarify and spread the right common sense, the `/tmpfile/` in Handle is important, but not in StripPrefix, let's say `http.Handle("/tmpfiles/", http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))` will also work

Answer (score 18):

#### Assume that

I have a file

```
/home/go/src/js/kor.js
```

Then, tell fileserve serves local directory

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/go/src/js"))
```

#### Example 1 - root url to Filerserver root

Now file server takes `"/"` request as `"/home/go/src/js"+"/"`

```
http.Handle("/", fs)
```

Yes, `http://localhost/kor.js` request tells Fileserver, find `kor.js` in

```
"/home/go/src/js" +  "/"  + "kor.js".
```

we got `kor.js` file.

### Example2 - custom url to Fileserver root

But, if we add additional resquest name.

```
http.Handle("/static/", fs)
```

Now file server takes `"/static/"` request as `"/home/go/src/js"+"/static/"`

Yes, `http://localhost/static/kor.js` request tells Fileserver, find `kor.js` in

```
"/home/go/src/js" +  "/static/"  + "kor.js".
```

We got 404 error.

### Example 3 - custom url to Fileserver root with

so, we modify request url before Fileserver takes it with  `http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", ...`

after `stripPrefix` Fileserver take `/` instead `/static/`

```
"/home/go/src/js" +  "/"  + "kor.js".
```

got `kor.js`

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the two questions one by one.

**Answer 1 to Question 1:**
If your code is written like below:

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
```

your root folder is `%GOPATH%/src/project_name/static/`. When you access `localhost:8080/static`, the URL `/static` will be forwarded to the handler returned by [http.FileServer()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer). However, you have no directory or file named `static` in the root folder.

**Answer 2 to Question 2**: In general, you cannot access `/static` folder if you remove the [http.StripPrefix()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix). However, if you have a directory or file named `static`, you can access it (*exactly not the root directory you want*) with the URL `localhost:8080:/static`.

By the way, you cannot access anything if your URL does not begin with `/static`, because the `http.ServeMux` will not redirect your request.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues with subdirectories, you need to add a `"."` because it seems it treats the path as relative only if it's a folder in the root directory of the binary.

For example

```
s.router.PathPrefix("/logos/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/logos/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./uploads/logos/"))))
```

Note the `"."` before "`/uploads`"