# serving static files in different locations

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a Go Application that serves files in two different directories.

My project structure:

```
PROJECT_DIR
PROJECT_DIR/config
PROJECT_DIR/src
PROJECT_DIR/client
PROJECT_DIR/client/node_modules
PROJECT_DIR/client/www
```

in my main go file i start the file server using the following code:

```
func main() {
log.Print("started web server...");
httpsPortStr := ":" + strconv.FormatUint(config.CfgIni.HttpsPort, 10)
log.Printf("starting https web server at port %v", config.CfgIni.HttpsPort)
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("client/www")))
http.Handle("/node_modules",http.FileServer(http.Dir(("client/node_modules"))))
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(httpsPortStr, config.CfgIni.CertificateFile, config.CfgIni.PrivateKeyFile, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("https server stopped with the following error: %v", err)
} else {
    log.Print("https server stopped with no error")
}
}
```

as you can see I mapped `/` to client/www and `/node_modules` to client/node_modules.

when I try to access files on client/www for example https://host:port/test.html, it works great!

when I try to access files on client/node_modules for example: https://host:port/node_modules/test.html, I get 404 page not found.

test.html file exists in both location and is readable (no permission problems).

I'm probably configuring the routing wrong somehow.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileServer is trying to route paths such as /node_modules/... to the file "client/node_modules/node_modules/..."

So use [StripPrefix](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix), eg:

```
http.Handle("/node_modules", http.StripPrefix("/node_modules", http.FileServer(http.Dir(("client/node_modules")))))
```

See another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files) here.

Comment: thanks. i needed to provide the first parameter to http.Handle, the following value: "/node_modules/" (an ending / to the directory). now it works