# How to serve index.html on non root path using golang

Tags: go, webserver

I want to serve my angular app `index.html` under `localhost:3000/mypath/` is there a way to accomplish that?

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // This works
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./my-project/dist/")))

    // This doesn't work, you get 404 page not found
    http.Handle("/mypath/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./my-project/dist/")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You'll have to use [`StripPrefix`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) since your index file lives in `"./my-project/dist/"` and not in `"./my-project/dist/mypath/"`. Example: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix

Comment: Also see [Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files/27946132#27946132)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `/` handler, and change the `/mypath/` handler into the code below:

```golang
http.Handle("/mypath/", http.StripPrefix("/mypath/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./my-project/dist/"))))
```

---

The `http.StripPrefix()` function is used to remove the prefix of the requested path. On your current `/mypath` handler, every request will be prefixed with `/mypath/`. Take a look at the example below.

```
/mypath/index.html
/mypath/some/folder/style.css
...
```

If the requested URL path is not stripped, then (as per the above example) it'll point to the below respective locations, **which is incorrect path**, and will result in `file not found` error.

```
./my-project/dist/mypath/index.html
./my-project/dist/mypath/some/folder/style.css
...
```

By stripping the `/mypath`, it'll point to the below locations, the correct one.

```
./my-project/dist/index.html
./my-project/dist/some/folder/style.css
...
```