# 404 error when serving files in paths not root

Tags: go, google-app-engine-golang

I am running this command "go run webapp/main.go." The reason is that app engine will call my app from the root directory, so I changed the paths to work from calling the file from root. I also do not mind if you have Go best practices tips.

```
└── webapp
    ├── app.yaml
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── index.css
    │   └── img
    ├── main.go
    ├── main_test.go
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```

Confused on how something so trivial can be wrong. localhost:8080/css/index.css works fine. I also have another handler function to serve localhost:8080/static/css/index.css, but I get a 404 error. Everything was working smoothly when I was using the command "go run main.go" and remove "webapp" from the code. Still, how can it work with / and not /static/. As can be seen in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997908/6828897 answer, it should serve ./webapp/assets/static as a dir. I also have tried http.StripPrefix but no luck either.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
    "text/template"
)

type templateHandler struct {
    once     sync.Once
    filename string
    templ    *template.Template
}

// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("webapp", "templates", t.filename)))
    })
    if err := t.templ.Execute(w, r); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing template: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func main() {
    dir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    log.Printf("dir: %s", dir)

    // command flags
    var addr = flag.String("addr", ":8080", "The addr of the application.")
    flag.Parse()

    // env variables
    envPort := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if envPort != "" {
        envPort = ":" + envPort
        addr = &envPort
    }

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./webapp/assets"))
    http.Handle("/static/", fs)

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", *addr)

    // http.Handle("/", &templateHandler{filename: "index.html"})

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(*addr, fs); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"how can it work with / and not /static/"*

Because you are passing `fs` directly to `ListenAndServe`, that means that the [`DefaultServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DefaultServeMux) which is used by `http.Handle("/static/", fs)` is being ignored / overridden.

[`http.Handle`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle):

> Handle registers the handler for the given pattern **in the
> DefaultServeMux**. The documentation for ServeMux explains how patterns
> are matched.

[`http.ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe)

> ListenAndServe listens on the TCP network address addr and then calls
> Serve with handler to handle requests on incoming connections.
> Accepted connections are configured to enable TCP keep-alives.
>
> **The handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is
> used.**
>
> ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error.

So in general what you should do is something like this:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./webapp/assets"))
// register fs for "/static/" in DefaultServeMux
http.Handle("/static/", fs)
// start listening at addr and serve incoming requests
// using DefaultServeMux as the router (because nil).
if err := http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

If there are other issues in your setup it is possible that your app may not work as desired right away, however this change is certainly a requirement to get closer to that goal.